# UWP: Scrolling ListView to focus on item

Tags: uwp

I have two ListViews in my app, both identical in layout:

```
<ListView x:Name="TextContent"
          SelectionChanged="LineSelected">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:TextLine>
                  <Grid>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                 Height="16"
                                 Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                                 Text="{Binding LineNumber}"/>
                      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                 Height="16"
                                 Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                                 Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                   </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The difference between the two ListViews is that the second one contains a filter, which will only display certain items based on a criteria.

I add items to this list representing lines (line number and a text). When I select a line in one ListView, I want to select the same line (based on line number) in the other ListView.

Here is the code for the items I push into the list:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    internal class TextLine
    {
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as TextLine;

            return 
                this.LineNumber == other.LineNumber &&
                this.Text.Equals(other.Text);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.LineNumber.GetHashCode() ^ this.Text.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

- **ListView.ScrollIntoView** did nothing... I passed an item as the argument.
- Got the ScrollViewer from the ListView's visual tree and tried **ChangeView**, but it did not work either.

The problem: If I select item X in ListView A, then I want to select item X in ListView B and scroll to it automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try to set the datatemplates datatype to the type of the objects you are putting in the listview? Or the datacontext of the listview?

Comment: I added that, but no change. Still does not scroll.

Comment: Hello @Christoffer , did you override the `Equal` method in the type of `TextLine` you provided? When using the `ListView.ScrollIntoView()` method, the code will use the comparator to compare the incoming parameters.

Comment: I have done that now (updated the post with that code) but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Hello @Christoffer , Can you provide a minimal reproducible demo? I simply tested the existing code and it works fine.